# Can Bias-Variance Decomposition be applied to find MSE of a linear model?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff

I'm trying to apply the Bias-Variance Decomposition to the produced estimates of a linear model.

$X = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$

$θ = [2,15,27,36,48,57,63,73,80,95]$

Linear model$ = 5 + 10x$

Estimated values from model for each $X$

$\hat{\theta} = [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95]$

---

[image]

---

No matter how the bias-square is calculated, it has to be some negative number to bring the $MSE$ to $6$. I've tried a ton of variations and the one that gets me the closest is:

Calculated $bias^2 = E[(E[\hat{\theta}]^2 - θ^2))] = -753.0$

---

So my question is: when does $MSE = bias^2 + variance$? Or what error am I making in the calculations?

Comment: did you compute those statistics? Although I've not gone through the computations, would wonder if they are accurate. MSE always equals bias^2+variance+irreducible error